# How to write function in Dart that returns count of positive number on a list?

Tags: list, dart, methods, filter

I am having trouble how to filter out other than positive numbers from the list in Dart. Example below:

```
 main() {
        var list = [];
       
        list.add(-1);
        list.add(0);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(4);
        
        var positiveSum = positive(list);
        print('Positive numbers: $positiveSum');
    }

positive(list) {
  
  var positive = 0;
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    positive = list.length;
  }
  return positive;
}
```

Now it returns all numbers from the list. Could not figure out how to use where method or something else. I am total beginner and have done maybe 20 hours of very basic exercises...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.where`:

```dart
var positiveNumbers = list.where((x) => x > 0);
```

If you just want to know the count of positive numbers, then that's:

```dart
var positiveNumberCount = list.where((x) => x > 0).length;
```

The `positiveNumbers` result is an iterable, its elements are computed lazily when you iterate the iterable. If you want to create a list instead, you can do:

```dart
var positiveNumbers = list.where((x) => x > 0).toList();
```

or

```
var positiveNumbers = [for (var x in list) if (list > 0) x];
```